# Generating heat map on the server side

Tags: mongodb, server-side, heatmap

I'm currently working on a big data application with position data. I have about 1 TB of JSON data in a database (currently MongoDB, but I'm exploring other alternatives). Generating a heat map on the client side with that amount of data will take forever. So I'm looking into solutions where the client requests data in a specific time period, the server selects the data and generates a heat map, and then the server sends the heat map back to the client where it can be shown to the user. This should be much faster than a client side rendering.

What solutions are out there and what tools should I look into?

Comment: Umm, that sounds like weird logic. I mean the costly part will be processing the data and by the sounds of it client side and server side will have the same amount of processing...I'm not sure if you planned this very well

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough. Sending 1TB of data to the browser to then generate a heat map will just cause it to crash. Perhaps I need to clean the data on the server, create a matrix with the positon data, count the occurences in the matrix, and then push it to the browser to generate the heat map?

Comment: Yes, sending 1TB will be tough but what happens when you scale and you have 30TB of data needing to be sharded across multiple dcs and users? Your current setup simply won't work, I would reorganise what you're doing